# Service Error Spreadsheets - working script now not

Tags: service

Quite new to this but the following code worked fine once but now throws the service error: spreadsheets message.  Can't work out why, please help :-)

```
function duplicatetemplate() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var NameRange = ss.getRangeByName("data");

    var Names = NameRange.getValues();

    for (var i=0; i < Names.length; i++) {

        ss.getSheetByName('Template T T')
           .copyTo(ss).setName(Names[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

The entries in the data range are unique.

I'm tearing my hair out!!  Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm trying to use Google Script code in Google Sheets to duplicate a template sheet ('Template T T') and rename each of the duplicates using the array of names that are in the range i've created call "data"